# Canvas / JS Таймер обратного отсчета

Tags: javascript, canvas, время, таймер, countdowntimer

Пробую реализовать таймер обратного отсчета на canvas. Застопорился в непонимании, почему данные не присваиваются так как я думаю. Приведу пример

```js
// Timer

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 205;
canvas.height = 46;

ctx.font = "500 31px Matricha, sans-serif";
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF0A";
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';


var m1 = 1;
var c1 = 2;
var c2 = 2;


//// m1 : c1 c2

var counter = counterFunction(c2);

function counterFunction(i) {

  var currentNumber = i;


  return function() {

    currentNumber = currentNumber - 1;
    console.log(currentNumber);
    if (currentNumber < 0) {

      if (c1 > 0) {
        currentNumber = 9; // Почему не происходит замена  ?
        return c1 = c1 - 1;
      } else {

        if (m1 > 0) {
          m1 = m1 - 1;
          c1 = 5;
        } else {
          m1 = 0;
          c2 = 0;
          c1 = 0;
        }

      }

    }
    return currentNumber
  };


}


function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillText(m1 + ":" + c1 + counter(), 100, 23);
}

setInterval(redraw, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #00FF0A;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Таймер я представил в виде трех значений m1 : c1c2. А теперь собственно вопросы - Подскажите, пожалуйста почему когда в моем случае c2<0 у меня не происходит переприсвоение переменной c1=9 ? (вообще на первой минуте 9 не выводит) и Ещё вопрос как остановить данный таймер на 0:00. и можно ли добиться что бы элементы canvas-а не менял свое местоположение в пространстве каждую секунду ?

Comment: я не понял про что вопрос и причем тут canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 205;
canvas.height = 46;

ctx.font = "500 31px Matricha, sans-serif";
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF0A";
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

setCounter(1, 11);

function setCounter(min, sec) {
  var interval = setInterval(redraw, 1000);

  function redraw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillText(counter(), 100, 23);
  }

  function counter() {
    sec = (sec == 0) ? 59 : sec - 1;

    if (sec == 0) {
      if (min > 0) {
        min = min - 1;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }

    return addZero(min) + ':' + addZero(sec);
  }

  function addZero(n) {
    return n > 9 ? n : "0" + n;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #00FF0A;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Спасибо Оптимусу, за объяснения